# Regular connection failure for 3 seconds (Windows 10)

Tags: windows-10, networking

I am getting regular network connection failures every 30 minutes or so for 3 seconds. Ping to 8.8.8.8 looks like this:

[image]

I've been experiencing this for the last 2 weeks and I can't remember doing anything in particular when this issue appeared. Doesn't seem to be the router problem since other PCs that are connected to it don't have this issue. My PC is connected to router through ethernet cable. I tried switching ports but the issue remained. Thus I can conclude that the cause of this problem is in software or hardware of my PC.

What might be causing this and how can I diagnose it?
Thank you.

Comment: Are there any other devices conencted via ethernet?

Comment: What is your network adapter and is its driver updated? Have you tried another adapter (even an external one)?

Comment: @Randomhero, there's one more PC connected to router and there's no connection problems.

Comment: @harrymc, I have Intel® Ethernet Connection I219-V adapter (as a part of the motherboard) with driver version 12.19.0.16 which was updated 29.09.2020 if I interpret this correctly.

Comment: There is a recent [new driver from Intel](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/products/sku/82186/intel-ethernet-connection-i219v/downloads.html). Reboot after installing. If it doesn't help, consider trying another adapter.